# Login token Axios post request gets Unauthorized response

Tags: reactjs, api, post, axios, token

I am encountering some difficulties while trying to update some data in a mysql database.
I am making an axios post request towards this api and inside the header I am sending the token that I receive from the backend after succesfull login.
I will show here the apiDocumentation and the POST req that I am making because I really don't understand how to send the login token to have authorization to the data.
Any help would very helpfull.

This is the backend apiDocumentation:

```
"post": {
    "summary": "Post new data row",
    "description": "Post new data row",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "token",
        "in": "header",
        "required": true,
        "description": "token",
        "schema": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "requestBody": {
      "required": true,
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "data": {
                "type": "string",
                "example": "{\"test\":1}"
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "example": "1"
              },
              "status": {
                "type": "integer",
                "example": 1
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "data",
              "type"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

This is my Post request that I am doing in my code:

```
case "newsTitle" :{
            const {titlu} = this.state;
            data = JSON.stringify(titlu);
    const token = this.props.history.location.state.token;
    const headers = {
                //"token":token
                "Authorization": token,
                'Accept': '*/*',
                //"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                "Content-Type":"application/json"

            };
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, data, headers);
            console.log("response::", response);
```

Comment: try `"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` ` or `"Authorization": "Bearer" + " "  + token`

Comment: Hi @UmairRiaz and thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately I receive the same response...:(

Comment: Please post the response

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
case "newsTitle" :{
            const {titlu} = this.state;
            data = JSON.stringify(titlu);
    const token = this.props.history.location.state.token;
    const headers = {
                //"token":token
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                'Accept': '*/*',
                //"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                "Content-Type":"application/json"

            };
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, data, headers);
            console.log("response::", response);
```